My EC2 Linux Instance on AWS can't connect to internet
I deployed an linux image from amazon on EC2 instance and I wanted to install some dependencies like pip and selenium. But it seems like my instance is not reaching the internet. I made sure to have public Ip address to my instance, I create a public subnet, which I assigned a route table with internet gateway to 0.0.0./0 target according to AWS documentation.
But still I can't install dependencies. Below are some screenshots that represent parts of my configuration:
My inbound and outbound settings
My Network interface
My associated routing table
Network ACL
Now when I connect to my instance using SSH I tried sudo yum update -y but I just get a loading state of progress and it sort of 'freezes':
First screenshot of error
Then after a while I get this timeout error:
Second screenshot of error
I also tried ping google.com and it says Name of Service not known.
I am new into AWS and learning about Cloud Computing so any help or feedback on this is appreciated!

Nothing I can see is obviously wrong. Suggest you delete you instance / VPC / create a new set with the wizard. Use a more standard unroutable CIDR range like 192.168.0.0/16 for your VPC. Make sure you add an S3 gateway endpoint to the VPC, it's free and helps with Linux updates by giving you a more direct route to the updates in S3 buckets.
